# "the" vs "it" vs "one"

Tags: grammar

In the following example, can I use **the truck**, **it**, and **one** interchangeably? Are they all correct?

> - Yesterday my friend told me someone had parked a truck in our playground but when I got there I could not see **the truck**.
> - Yesterday my friend told me someone had parked a truck in our playground but when I got there I could not see **it**.
> - Yesterday my friend told me someone had parked a truck in our playground but when I got there I could not see **one**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, yes, you could use any of the three.

Repeating "the truck" is the least likely, but it is still possible.

"One" says that you could not see any trucks there; "it" says that you could not see the particular truck, but leaves open that there might have been other trucks there.

Comment: Other options would include: _I could not see **any**_ (or _see any **truck**_); _I could not see **a truck**; I could see **no truck**_ (or _see **no trucks**_).